# Can i buy Visual Studio 2010 individually?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdn

I am confused a bit by MSDN (microsoft) site. Do i really need to get subscription of MSDN in order to get Visual Studio 2010?

I dont' need MSDN or I really can't afford MSDN. I just wanna buy Visual Studio 2010. Any help here?

Answer (score 2):

I bought VS2010 from the MS store. It comes with a limited version (MSDN essentials) of MSDN. I think its sort of a "bonus" deal. But the price is the same as without it so you might as well go for it.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you could, but a quick check on [Amazon (UK)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_i_0?rh=i:software,k:visual+studio+2010&keywords=visual+studio+2010&ie=UTF8&qid=1272294319) seems to indicate that all the retail versions come with some form of MSDN subscription or Team Foundation Server. I'm guessing that you're an individual developers so you wouldn't want the TFS version.

Have you checked out the [Express editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)?

Comment: Free edition wont' help me. I already have VS2008 Professional Edition, which i bought individually. but now question is How and from where I can buy VS2010 individually.

Comment: @user35249 - ah. I'm actually in the same boat, though having MSDN could be useful, you'd get Expression.

Answer (score 0):

> I already have VS2008 Professional Edition

Then you could try the upgrade:
[http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Studio-2010-Pro-Upgrade/dp/B0039829OK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0039829OK)

Comment: The UK equivalent comes with "MSDN essentials" http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Visual-Professional-Essentials-Upgrade/dp/B0039829OK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=software&qid=1272296362&sr=8-1